# Can I use an existing dataset in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-2008-r2, crystal-reports, sql-server-data-tools

Related to a 
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37488555/can-i-create-ssrs-reports-in-vs-2015-using-sql-server-2008-r2) I've asked earlier regarding SSRS, could anyone please tell me - Is it possible to reuse an existing dataset in SSRS?

I know we can have shared datasets and we can convert a dataset to a shared one too.

Currently we are using Crystal Reports. We are trying to migrate to SSRS. So we were trying to reuse the existing dataset which we've used to create Crystal Reports. There is no option I could see to convert this dataset to a shared dataset so that I can reuse it. I could see the option to convert **a new** dataset to a shared dataset but not an old one. Or else what are the other options?

We're using VisualStudio 2015, SSDT for VisualStudio 2015, SQL Server 2008 R2.

Hope someone could help me.

Answer (score 2):

SSRS can't use a Crystal Reports Dataset.   But you can take the same query you used from Crystal Reports and paste it into a new Dataset in SSRS.

Comment: Thanks Tab. They are not query based datasets. We've DataAccess classes to get the stored procedures and report adapters to pass the data to the datasets. Here the datasets are a set of tables defined and will get filled by the report adapters.

Comment: Ok, well the best you can do is use them as "recipes" for creating new SSRS datasets, then.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS datasets are specific to SSRS reports, you can't migrate dataset from any other reporting service to SSRS. In your case, you can create a new dataset similar to crystal report by copying your query in new SSRS dataset and by refreshing the parameters/fields values in report being used with that dataset.

In case dataset is to be used by multiple reports you can use shared dataset.