# Deploy of a report with SSDT 2016 generates error

Tags: sql-server, deployment, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2016

I use VS2015 with SQL Server Data Tools; I have some Reporting Services (RDL) reports.

I want to deploy them to a Reporting Server with **SQL Server 2014** installed.

In my report project I set the `TargetServerVersion` to **"SQL Server 2008R2, 2012 or 2014"**, but the deploment process fails with an error similar to:

```
Report Definition invalid, because namespace .../2016/... invalid.
```

Comment: You might need to edit the code directly to change that to the previous namespace. I've had to do that before.  <Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">

Comment: Simply opening a report with the newer SSDT changes the `xmlns` immediately and a new parameters section to the xml. Neither of which are likely to work on the production SSRS 2012 my current project is using. As per the question I also have the target version set to 2008r2-2014 which you'd think would do the job. Good thing I still have a VM with VS2013 and the older SSDT installed.

Comment: Same problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f50640bb-82e1-48b9-b111-4fd64f562471/vs2015-produces-invalid-report-definition-targeting-ssrs-2012?forum=ssdt

Comment: How did you deploy them? From this http://stackoverflow.com/q/39188874/10245 it seems that uploading the `.rdl` directly to ssrs won't work, but using the publish function or grabbing them from the bin folder will.

Comment: I just deployed a report to a 2008 instance of SSRS using VS 2015 and SSDT 14.0.61021.0 (SSRS designer v. 13.0.1701.8). Worked! I don't have a 2014 version of SSRS propped up anywhere to try that. Have you tried to Rebuild the SSRS project?

Comment: @TimAbell The link you have provided should resolve the issue. We struggled with it for a while until we figured it out. We are currently using VS2015 to develop and deploying to SQL 2008 R2 using the SharePoint integration. We have a current project to upgrade to SQL 2014 and while I am not involved with the testing, my understanding is that there have not been any issues deploying. Let me know if you can`t make this work because we may need to look more closely on our side!

Comment: @SMM yep you are correct, I've actually just tested exactly that and VS succesfully downgrades the schema and strips out incompatible xml before putting the result in the `bin/` folder.

Comment: Remind me to vote to close this as a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/39188874/10245 when my bounty expires. SO won't let me at the moment. I wasn't originally sure if it was the same issue but having experimented locally with various SSRS versions I'm no sure it is.

Comment: I've now updated https://github.com/timabell/ssrs-powershell-deploy with a contribution from one of the forks that makes it read from the bin folder instead of the source folder, and my deploy now succeeds to a SSRS 2012 server.

Comment: @TimAbell I have added an update to the answer with some clarification from another answer if you want to have a look. I forgot that I had 2 answers to similar questions :-). I have flagged the other as a duplicate.

Comment: Nice one, thanks. Looks good

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSRS 2014 report deploy issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188874/ssrs-2014-report-deploy-issue)

Comment: @TimAbell It's seems you forget to close this one as duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved. You "MUST" recompile your report project and immediately afterwards you can deploy your reports without any problem.